# Get a list of quota usage/limit of my project using gcloud command line

Tags: google-compute-engine, admin, gcloud, quota

Can anyone show me how to get a list of used quota per project in GCE cloud?

I can only get this list from console: `console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=my-project&location=us-east1`. but I don't know who we can listed using gcloud command line.?

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command to check project-wide quotas. Replace `myproject` with your own project ID:

`gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject`

Official reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota)

Comment: Thanks Barak for your help, I ran this command before but it didn't give me what I need exactly ,like for example I need to get a quota usage for Committed local SSD disk reserved (GB) , Persistent Disk Standard (GB) and Local SSD (GB) where this command that you mention don't.

Answer (score 3):

To verify the capacity used vs available quota, you can run the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota).

$ gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject

Or you can interact with [Compute engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/get) to list some quotas and their limit, but the Persistent Disk or Local SSD… are a regional quota and the results of the command-line or Compute engine API  don't list per-region quotas. In order to retrieve information regarding regional quota, you have to run:

$ gcloud compute regions describe example-region

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get all quotas per region with this command:
`gcloud compute regions list --project=production --format=json`